# How to ensure the SoundId changes for a sound (Roblox Studio)

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

I am trying to write a code to change the SoundId of a Sound Instance for a player depending on whether they touch a block or not. However, I do not want the SoundId to be changed if the correct Sound is already playing for a player. I used a remote event to ensure that the correct song is only playing for the client (Player) and not the server. However, the SoundId of the song playing for the player does not seem to change which results in the remoteEvent being fired several times. Why does this happen?

LocalScript for the RemoteEvent

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PlayMusic
local player = Players.LocalPlayer

local function changeMusic(newSong)
    local song1 = player.Songs.CurrentlyPlaying:FindFirstChildOfClass("Sound")
    if song1 then
        song1:Stop()
        song1:Destroy()
        song1 = Instance.new("Sound", player.Songs.CurrentlyPlaying)
        song1.SoundId = newSong.SoundId
        song1:Play()
    else
        warn("Currently playing song not found.")
    end
end

remoteEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(changeMusic)
```

Script for the RemoteEvent

```
local mySong = script.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("Sound")
local musicBox = script.Parent
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PlayMusic

musicBox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local char = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if char then
        local plr = players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(char.Parent)
        if plr then
            local currentlyPlaying = plr.Songs.CurrentlyPlaying.Sound
            local mySong = musicBox:FindFirstChildOfClass("Sound")
            if mySong then
                print("Song 1: ", currentlyPlaying and currentlyPlaying.SoundId, "\nSong 2: ", mySong.SoundId)
                if currentlyPlaying.SoundId ~= mySong.SoundId then
                    remoteEvent:FireClient(plr, mySong)
                end
                wait()
                currentlyPlaying = plr.Songs.CurrentlyPlaying
            else
                warn("No sound found in musicBox")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Sound Instance created by the client doesn't replicate to the server